# Matlab %e meaning

Tags: matlab, percentages

What does %e mean in matlab? I.e:

```
x = %1.25e
```

I know if you put an e at the end it adds 0s, so does it have something to do with that?

Answer (score 1):

The `%` sing in matlab is used as a comment.
The line

```
x = %1.25e
```

doesn't work since it is the same as writing only

```
x =
```

I think you mean the usage of `%e` when formatting strings:

```
fprintf('%e',5)
```

which will print the number 5 in eponenial notation. Further informations on format specification you can get by typing `doc fprintf` in your matlab console.